# Using regex to get passage between two strings in Python

Tags: python

I want to parse all of the functions inside of a .txt file. It looks like this:

```
def
  test
end

def
  hello
end

def
  world
end
```

So, I would get the following returned: `[test, hello, world]`

Here is what I have tried, but I do not get anything back:

```
    r = re.findall('def(.*?)end', doc)
    print r
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag which will allow `.` to match newlines too (since your `doc` is multi-line).

You could additionally use '^def' and '^end' in the regex if you only wanted the outer def/end blocks (ie ignore indented ones), in which case you would also need to use the `re.MULTILINE` flag, which allows '^' and '$' to match start/end of *line* (as opposed to start/end of *string*).

```
re.findall('^def(.*?)^end',doc,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: how can I get from this: doc = "{'content': 'LAND.L', 'href'" the expression 'LAND.L' ? I tried: "'content':(.*?),\b'href'", but It did not work. thanks!

Comment: corrected to: re.findall("[^\']content[^\']:(.*?)[^\']href[^\']", a), but it still does not work. it returns a.

Comment: How can i get from whole words? For example getting passages between "my title" and "my end". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
r = re.findall('def(.*?)end', doc, re.S)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `re.MULTILINE` flag to match multiple lines in a single regular expression.
Also, `^` and `$` do **NOT** match linefeeds (`\n`)

```
>>> re.findall(r"^def$\n(.*)\n^end$", doc, re.MULTILINE)
['  test', '  hello', '  world']
```

If you don't want to match the whitespace in the beginning of the blocks, add `\W+`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"^def$\n\W*(.*)\n^end$", text, re.MULTILINE)
['test', 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: re.MULTILINE only converst '^' and '$' to per-line instead of per-string operators. It won't help in the case of a multiline input (as opposed to a multiline regex).